# need scalable solution to php echo variable based on a new record ID using semi-colon text file

Tags: php, html

What I have not is not scaleable... What I have is a set amount in a database and I echo the information in my php document like this...

database

```
SCD 0; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:54:40 ;
SCD 1; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.56 ; 16:54:40 ;
SCD 2; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.57 ; 16:54:40 ;
```

so my echo looks like this

```
<div class="scdenvelope" style="display: <?php echo ( trim($rack['SCD 0']) == 'wfbscd13') ? 'yes' : 'none'; ?>;"></div>
```

with my method now I need to code each line but every time I need to encode each locator specificly [SCD 0], [SCD 1], etc....

How would I change the above line (my echo) so it's based on a new record [SCD ?] so it is scaleable?

here is the var to be complete but it's probably not what we're looking at.

```
<?php

$scd = array();
if (($handle = fopen($statfile, "r")) !== FALSE)
{
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
        if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'SCD')
        {
            $board = trim($data[0]);
            $temp = $data[2];
            $rack[ $board ] = $temp;
         }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: I think you are beng just slightly too cryptic. Its really not clear what you want to do, or where you want to do it. See [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I agree to disagree... Specifically I limit myself right now with because I need to number the index's in each echo. I don't want to do that because someday there might be 20 index's SCD 20

Comment: `database

SCD 0; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.55 ; 16:54:40 ;
SCD 1; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.56 ; 16:54:40 ;
SCD 2; #ff9900 ; wfbscd13 ; 158.140.161.57 ; 16:54:40 ;` that part I don't understand. Are those stored values in seperate rows?

Comment: Are you asking how do I make the `$scd` array hold the output from many rows in the csv file all of which start with `SCD` in the first 3 cols of `$data[0]` Also when you say `database` do you mean the `CSV` file or is there a real database somewhere

Comment: yes they are used for different functions in the SCD catagory... Listing server name, time, ipaddress...

Comment: no, more basic question than that I think I'm asking how to make it so the index in the square brackets can be a variable based on an index that hasn't happened but could happen...

Comment: Try adding **1.** This is the inputs **2.** This is the desired outputs

Comment: That worked RiggsFolly can you post it as an answer so I can accept it and you get credit?

Comment: and Thank you, as always I'll pay it forward.

Comment: **Now I am really confused** _What worked_ I must be a genious, I didnt understand the question, I didnt give an answer _or so I thought_ and now you want me to post the answer I didnt give. **Guess you get this one for free**

Comment: You didn't specifically answer my question but I just realized I can use a wildcard and adjust that in the var itself... I'll post my answer to my question in about 30 minutes... but it's great having a head to bounce off of.